# PHP Excel, but no Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Tags: php, excel, pear, xls

I need to save some data in .xls file. I am trying to use PEAR library Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer. It is work. But now i am working with hosting without PEAR. Of cause, it is very terrible.

Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer has a lot of dependencies. I need a module or code, which i can include in my scripts.

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Spreadsheet Writer a lot and it's nice to have, but if you don't need multiple sheets or the ability to do some formatting, etc, you an always just output HTML and send a

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

and an extension of ".xls" and then Excel or OpenOffice's spreadsheet program (and I assume, I guess, Mac's spreadsheet program) will open it and format the HTML as a spreadsheet.

It's not a native solution but in the end, it looks pretty good to the end-user.  You have to use tables in your html but you can add colors/borders, padding, font changes, rowspan, colspan, etc, for a bit of control.  No functions or formulas or multiple sheets, though.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little-known format that never really caught on, but MS Office has support for so-called Excel 2003 XML files - which are indeed XML and, at a bare minimum, look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Worksheet>
    <Row>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">First</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
   </Worksheet>
 </Workbook>
```

You could generate this quite simply without any PHP extensions, and it will open correctly in any version of MS Excel since 2003. OpenOffice 2 and 3 will open these correctly if you rename the file extension to `.xls.xml`

When a user opens this file and saves it from Excel, it will be, by default, converted to the classic XLS file.

As @Alexander.Plutov notes in a comment, there is [a library for writing these files](http://dustweb.ru/log/2008/08/01/write_excel_php/).

There's a useful (and more comprehensive) page on IBM's site about this format and PHP: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/#N101F7

Comment: I wonder where this answer is supposed to be wrong; I've successfully used the Excel 2003 XML format this way, on several occasions, and it works. Care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it could be the use of string concatenation to build an xml file rather than XMLWriter or similar

Comment: @Mark Baker: Could be. I mentioned that to show that in an extreme case, no libraries are strictly necessary (had to do that once, in a constrained environment; but I agree that using a XMLWriter for writing XML makes sense in most cases). Edited that out.

Answer (score 3):

Literally, PHPExcel: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: He require a php_zip php_gd and php 5.2. Hosting of my customer hasn't this things. And php 5.16. Terrible hosting!

Comment: Some users have reported that PHPExcel will run on 5.1.6, and the php wrapper for zip/unzip binaries ( https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=254316 ) can be used instead of php_zip; and gd is only used if you work with images in your worksheets or use autocolumn sizing with rotated texts. However, I can't make any guarantees about that; and while I'm doing some work to try and reduce the requirements, it isn't priority.

Comment: Just a note on php 5.1.6: AFAIK It is the latest php version supported by Red Hat Enterprise Linux (5.#) and derivatives, realible distros with long time support. RHEL 6 with newer php was released yesterday(!)

Comment: @goorj: The circle of life indeed. If you worry too much about stability, you'll run into obsolescence. If you worry too much about new features, you'll run into instability and incompatibilities. (anyway, RHEL 6? Now *that's* good news!)

Answer (score 3):

Im using
http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/

I got it simply included in many projects and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Beware, the source code provided by Piskvor:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Worksheet>
    <Row>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">First</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
   </Worksheet>
 </Workbook>
```

is not a valid Excel file (at least in my version – Excel 2010) and will fail opening producing an error message, as it is missing two required values corrected in the following example (the missing part is that within a `WorkSheet` you need a `Table` and a `WorkSheet` must have a name specified as a string in `ss:Name`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
   <Worksheet ss:Name="test">
     <Table>
       <Row>
         <Cell>
           <Data ss:Type="String">First</Data>
         </Cell>
       </Row>
     </Table>
   </Worksheet>
 </Workbook>
```

This then becomes a valid excel spreadsheet indeed and thanks to Piskvor for reminding us of this wonderful open and machine- and human-readable format.